# How can I see in the App store whether I am working secure

Tags: google-play-store, 2.1-eclair, security

I wanted to buy some small application from the app store, it asked for my credit card information, but I was unsure whether we were working in secure mode.

How can you see, during payment, whether your are working in secure mode or not ? (like the green colour in Internet Explorer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you were purchasing through Android Market (App Store is iPhone), credit card payments are handled by Google Checkout.  (More info: http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=105916 )

Google Checkout API is secure even though you won't see an HTTPS indicator like you would for SSL-enabled sites in a web browser (e.g. the green location bar in Internet Explorer).

Comment: @J. Farray: I would expect the payment to be secure but the link you provided just tells that we can use credit cards, it doesn't mention whether it is secure. With security being so important these days, one would expect some clear indication when you are paying over https: or not. Still leaves me uncertain.

Comment: @Edelcom: The article I linked to states that purchases are handled by Google Checkout.  There are plenty of articles available about Google Checkout's security model.  The reason you don't have a "this is secure" indicator is because Google Checkout only operates over HTTPS.  There is no "unsecured" mode.

Comment: @ J.Farray: I agree, but still I, as a user, would like to see that I am working secure. Just stating somewhere in some documentation that the whole system is secure, is not enough, IMHO. We all tell our users of Windows browsers to certainly check the secure indicator as to not send your password and credit card information over a non secure link, but a 'new' operating system as Android does not give any indication that it works secure . That's an oversight in my book.

Answer (score 0):

No one is answering my question here ... so I presume it simply is not possible to view whether you are using a secure connection of not.

In this age, this is a great oversight, in my opinion.